# Is it possible to write libs in clojure and deployed in WSO2 as service to export?

Tags: clojure, wso2

anyone have tried a  web service written  in Clojure and  runing in WSO2 AS ?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 AS is based on apache tomcat. Therefore I think it should work. I haven't tried the scenario. You can create a war out of your clojure project and deploy it in the WSO2AS.
You can refer to http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/deployment.md#deploying_to_tomcat

Comment: It worked as a WAR file to deploy. thanks!  but is there any way to deploy as an AAR package?

Comment: I'm not quite sure of that. You have give a try and check :)